# When does a x100 2000V scope probe not work at 2000V?

Tags: oscilloscope, voltage-measurement, probe

I refer to [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B081T3TFSJ/) X100 scope lead, and to this relevant question & answer for that product:

> Q: According to the 4100 user's guide the voltage rating at 10 MHz is only 100 V. shouldn't it be 2000 V all the way to 100 MHz as implied in the spec?

> A: Sorry but no, that is normal for such probes. Even high priced Keysight and other top makers probes have similar deratings.

I assumed that I could use this lead to safely measure noise on the UK 240 V mains. That only runs @ 50 Hz (<< 10 MHz). Yet the input resistance is 100 megaohms. Can anyone explain or correct this?

Comment: Due to dielectric breakdown (or heating) due to dV/dt. You can simulate or calculate it yourself. Take the capacitance from the datasheet and calculate the current at X kV and Y MHz. What does your waveform look like and how do you generate it?

Comment: @winny I don't. It's the typical noise on the mains. Probably due to the next door neighbour's plasma cutter and my microwave.

Comment: Then no probe issues. Be careful measuring directly on mains!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you are missing how a probe would look like when you draw it as a circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEu7iQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With this, it might be easier to understand why in case of high frequencies the voltage divider and input impedance is not what it is for DC.

The 6 pF capacity will turn into a very small impedance like Andy Aka explained - and result in a high current if you would measure a source at that frequency.

For noise measurement this is no concern - if your noise at 10 MHz would be in the order of 100 V, you could harvest a lot of energy out of it. It's usually only millivolts.

Comment: Yep, that's got it. I forgot that C1 & R1 are paralleled in a scope probe. R1 would remain in place @ 50 Hz (fundamental). And then with much smaller noise riding on top of that.

Answer (score 2):

> *shouldn't it be 2000v all the way to 100 MHz as implied in the spec?*

Well, the Shamazon spec says this: -

> - *Input capacitance of 6 pF*
> - *Maximum operating voltage: 2 KV (Vp-p)*
> - *100:1 attenuation*

So, at 100 MHz, 6 pF has an impedance of 265 Ω. So, if you applied a 100 MHz sinewave of amplitude 707 volts RMS, that's a current into your probe of 2.67 amps RMS and that ain't happening big time.

> *Yet input resistance is 100 megaohms Can anyone explain or correct
> this?*

Standard (basic scope probes) have an input resistance of normally 1 MΩ. Most x10 probes offer 10 MΩ input resistance so, it makes sense that a probe that attenuates x100 has something like 100 MΩ input resistance.

---

The probe circuit will look something like this: -

[image]

Image modified (to focus on the important elements) from [here](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-1zdVzb7Btxs/W9dnzS9iV7I/AAAAAAAADI8/6SQb7-sM5gAFh-Vezsnwc8ZLh7mMihOXACLcBGAs/s1600/Figure%2B1.png)

So, at low frequencies, the input resistance is 99 MΩ + 1 MΩ. At high frequencies the input capacitance will be: -

$$\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{8}+\dfrac{1}{22}}\text{ pF} = 5.9\text{ pF}$$

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it. I get the capacitive impedance thing , but the x100 attenuation? That's only ~14V RMS after attenuation on a 2000 Vpp raw input. Then there's another 1 MΩ on the physical BNC connector inside the scope.

Comment: @PaulUszak I "don't get" what it is that you "don't get" about the specifications. What is it particularly that troubles you here? BTW it's 7.071 volts RMS not 14 volts.

Comment: I think the problem is "How can there be a 2.67 amps current, when the input impedance is 100 MOhm?"

Comment: Because you're talking about 707 VRMS, yet the probe divides that by 100 before it gets into the scope. I'm not doubting the specs, just trying to understand them...

Comment: @Arsenal if that's the issue here then that is simply resolved by the parallel arrangement of 100 Mohm of resistance and 6 pF of capacitance. At HF the capacitor is the dominant impedance of the two; at DC the resistor is the limiting factor.

Comment: @PaulUszak you said this: `I'm not doubting the specs, just trying to understand them` - what are your concerns here? I've tried to answer based on what you put in your question but, without clear guidance to the contrary, that's all I can do.